Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Однородный член или присоединение?

В первую очередь проект – это про командообразование, про
корпоративный дух, и только потом уже про экономику.


Правильно:
В первую очередь проект – это про командообразование, про корпоративный дух и только потом уже про экономику.
Пояснение

Выбор делается для конкретного предложения: И — замыкающий союз в однородном ряду дополнений. Частица ТОЛЬКО дифференцирует значение третьего члена, но при этом он входит в ряд.

С другой стороны, присоединительное значение возможно по Розенталю, да и в Нацкорпусе встречаются разные варианты: обособление запятой или тире, а таже запись отдельным предложением.

Но в заданном предложении уже есть тире, так что разделение однородного ряда нежелательно.



Знаки препинания расставлены верно. Только потом уже про экономику однородным членом быть не может, потому что есть уже в первую очередь.
В первую очередь проект – это про командообразование, про корпоративный дух, и только потом уже про экономику.
Вместо запятой перед и можно поставить и точку.
Это присоединение.

@Sharon Да, я подумал об этом, прежде чем написать ответ. Но потом понял вот что. "Однородный" союз и очень безликий что ли, незаметный, соединяет и всё. А когда я вижу перед ним запятую, то он сразу превращается в "отдельную единицу". И для меня такое сочетание не перебивается предыдущим тире.

А моё решение по сути вопроса считаю не интересным, а единственно правильным: в первую очередь не может включать и потом уже.

@Sharon "только потом уже" идёт после союза, поэтому без запятой проскакивает, ты уже читаешь заключительный однородный член... а оказывается, что это не так, смысл и логика нарушены.

@Sharon Вот он и выпадает – запятая его отделила, вынесла из структуры. Идеально вписаться в ряд ему не позволяет смысл первого сообщения: "Проект в первую очередь – это про это, про это, а потом уже про это". // Хватит :))

@Sharon, почему вы удалили все комментарии?.. И не предупредили...

Эти комментарии можно пересказать двумя фразами: – Интересный у вас ответ. – Мой ответ не интересный, а единственно правильный. И подтекст: Как я вижу, так и правильно. // Но предложение не только видят, но еще и читают. Тогда объясните, как вы слышите, что там с паузами. Интонационное тире читать не будем? // А когда к диалогу подключаются минусовщики, то отпадает желание продолжать его. // Потом ваше неудовольствие распространяется на другие темы, и вместо обсуждения я слышу "Спасибо за мнение". А мнение можно понимать как ничем не доказанный ответ. И т. д.

Эффект бабочки, а что причиной? Наше эго, чья-то неприязнь извне, неумение взглянуть на ситуацию со стороны? И как остановить негатив?  / Впрочем, способ есть, это Хармс:  Некий Пантелей ударил пяткой Ивана.
Некий Иван ударил колесом Наталью...И началась драка... Елена била Татьяну забором... Эх,– думали мы, – дерутся хорошие люди. dzen.ru/a/XOEfF2ZJAwC0Rlu0   https://slova.org.ru/harms/siuita_iz_goluboy_tetradi/

@Sharon "Как я вижу, так и правильно" – вот уж нет. Никакого подтекста. // Читать будем всё. И графику я люблю. // Минусовщиков в калидор! Неудовольствие – чисто ваши ощущения. Вы почему-то ждёте быстрых реакций и обсуждений, а я, написав "Спасибо за мнение", только это и хотел сказать на данный момент, т.к. не могу проводить здесь часы. // На этот вопрос я ответил только потому, что увидел явную смысловую нестыковку, если не поставить знак перед "и". // Как остановить негатив? Не ждать его. А если пришёл, увидеть в нём позитив.

Александр, я тонкий "психолог", и о вас знаю больше, чем вы о себе.  "Спасибо за мнение" - это не ваша риторика, вы обычно приветливее и добрее, даже если у вас времени нет.   Кроме того,  заданное вами предложение действительно интересно и неоднозначно, но  дискуссия не состоялось.  Ну да ладно, может кто другое решение предложит. //Нестыковку  я пропустила, но я не виновата. Грамматика не выражает нужный смысл, поэтому данное предложение нужно перестраивать, вот что я хотела сказать. // А Хармс - это юмор, в котором отражены разговоры, подобные нашему.  Если посмотреть со стороны, то смешно.

И об интонации этого предложения, где там основная пауза? Там, где запятая?  А тире обозначает произносительную паузу?

@Sharon Вот опять всё не так :) Вы меня "узнали", но время идёт, и на сю-сю-му-сю действительно его нет, а слова приветствия и вежливые обороты между нами уже можно читать в скобках, как само собой разумеющееся. Я остаюсь вашим поклонником, слежу и часто плюсую. // Основная пауза на тире, запятая перед "и" показывает, что концовка не входит в ряд, и грамматика, и смысл на месте. Запятая не нарушает правила, но я бы поставил точку или многоточие.

Ладно, замнем для ясности)) Но почему-то песенка вспомнилась: Два кусочека колбаски У тебя лежали на столе, Ты рассказывал мне сказки,
Только я не верила тебе) // Голосуете, да, за Шекспира отдельное спасибо, его у нас откровенно не любят, так что я даже имя опасаюсь произносить.  Кому в наше время нужен этот Шекспир с его странными проблемами и стихами. // Не, по интонации объяснение не принимается.  Что же вы разделили эти опорные слова: в первую очередь, и только потом? Недаром вам хочется точку поставить, то есть что-то изменить.

@Sharon Да нормально всё с интонацией :), конец – это неполное присоединит. предложение. // И нормально всё с "верю не верю". Помню первое напряжение между нами, когда я написал что-то, что вы восприняли как неприязнь или даже грубость, а у меня и в мыслях не было, чесслово! И тогда я принял на заметку, а сейчас думаю, что из-за большого количества наездов на вас вы как бы ждёте этого негатива и пропускаете слова через свою призму недоверия.

Продолжаем разговор)) Предлагаю редактирование (убираю лишние слова для улучшения информативности текста): Этот проект –  про командообразование, про корпоративный дух и только потом уже про экономику.
